# Scrivener project statistics is showing an incorrect word count

Tags: novel, software, scrivener

I just purchased Scrivener yesterday and am trying to get it figured out.  After importing my manuscript, I cut and pasted it, separating it into the 23 chapters that are linked under "Manuscript" in the binder.

For some reason, when I go to Project: Project Statistics it shows only 158 words.  My entire manuscript is roughly 97,000.  I think it's only calculating statistics on the title page?

I don't know if I did something wrong when splitting it into chapters?  Or if I should've copied to paste it into the separate breaks instead of cut?

Can someone please help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure all the folders that contain the text are descendants of the main project folder.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to check the Include in Compile checkbox in the Notes Inspector (View → Inspect → Notes; ⌃⌥⌘H)

Section 21.3 in the manual is about goals and statistics tracking by the way.

Comment: This was my problem. I used this answer, and it was absolutely what had happened to my word count.